# how should i get perfect maven project structure?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testing

Creating new Maven project in eclipse(WebdriverTest) but not getting the actual structure of maven project like earlier project(WebdriverTestNew)???

```
WebdriverTest
            src
               main
                   java
                   resources
               test
                   java
                   resources
```

But why it is not coming like this

```
WebdriverTest
             src/main/java
             src/main/resources
             src/test/java
             src/test/resources
```

Comment: Where is the difference? The structure is the same it is just displayed a little different.

Comment: while creating maven project, java did not recognize by default. On project icon only "M" symbol appears. But actually both "M" & "J" symbol appears.

Comment: Just noticed, that the src folder has a capital "S" in the first snippet. This may cause the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Creating maven project in eclipse at the top level files descriptive of the project: a pom.xml
There are just two subdirectories of this structure: src and target
The target directory is used to house all output of the build.
The src directory contains all of the source material for building the project, it contains contains a subdirectory for each type: main for the main build artifact

[image]

Comment: while creating maven project, java did not recognize by default. On project icon only "M" symbol appears. But actually both "M" & "J" symbol appears.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is:

- use [archtype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) to generate the mavenized project. There are many archtypes, you can choose the one you need.
- do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate the eclipse project and then just import it to your eclipse ide.

Update: 
As pointed out by @khmarbaise, [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/index.html) is retired. Once the maven project structure is created using [archtypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html), then use [m2e](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.m2e) eclipse plugin to import the project.

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is long deprecated and you should use Eclipse to import a Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

File -> New -> Maven Project -> Next ->  type in the Filter `"webapp-j2ee14"`   it's the best archetype

Comment: if i am switching to another workspace and creating maven project over there then it is fine. but in that particular workspace i am getting this type of peoblem.